# wget -p does not download referenced files from external systems

Tags: wget

Using Windows I would like to download an entire website using `wget -p -e robots=off`. The site references Google fonts from the Google server, so it includes a line `<link rel='stylesheet' id='google-fonts-1-css'  href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu&#038;display=auto&#038;ver=6.0.3' media='all' />`

If I use wget 1.8.2 (I know, it's ancient) it properly downloads the site and creates a subdirectory fonts.googleapis.com that contains the downloaded font. If I use wget 1.21.3 it doesn't do that anymore, the font (and anything else that is referenced outside my site) is not downloaded.

How can I download/mirror an entire site and any objects it references using a current wget?

Comment: What `wget` are you using - WSL or someone's windows binaries?

Comment: The 1.21.3 ("GNU Wget 1.21.3, a non-interactive network retriever.") one I downloaded from https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget (https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/1.21.3/64/wget.exe), the 1.8.2 one ("GNU Wget 1.8.2, a non-interactive network retriever.") I found on my PC within an Insta360Studio2022 installation.

Comment: Try adding the flag `--restrict-file-names=windows` in case the newer wget is attempting to save the font version query as part of the name